# How to zip Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you zip a Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229549/how-do-you-zip-a-xcode-project)

Hey,

I have tried to send my friend some code(project), and well I zipped the folder which was created when i started the project.

But there are files missing.

Any idea how i can grab all the files easily ?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229549/how-do-you-zip-a-xcode-project/3229635#3229635

Comment: thanks but compress is not an option for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that all the files referenced from the project are inside the project directory? (When you add an existing file to a project you are asked whether to copy it or not, maybe you did not)

Comment: Im not sure if they are ? im very new to this , and i have no idea why its so complicated to just send someone my project.

Comment: just open your project directory in Finder and check if all the file you see from Xcode Project inspector are in that folder. If not, delete them from Xcode and re add them as existing files and when prompted to copy or not them mark the checkbox to copy

Comment: I just lost all my work! thanks for the advice rano :'(