# Zipping Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to send my friend my Xcode project that uses other files in the same directory as it. The directory looks like this:

[image: Directory]

I'm zipping the HelloCordova.xcodeproj and sending it to him through email but when opened the other files in the ios directory are missing. This includes the files in each folder inside the Xcode project:

[image: xcode proj]

Is there anyway to zip an Xcode project such that all the files it depends on are also included?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you zip a Xcode project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229549/how-do-you-zip-a-xcode-project)

Comment: As it says over there: "Make sure you're zipping the entire directory that contains the project. Just sending the .xcodeproj file and the source won't do it. You need the whole set of data."

Comment: Basically, right click the "ios" folder you have and click "compress". send him that .zip

Comment: Right click on your Xcode Project. (HelloCordova). Click show in Finder. Now from finder, archive(Compress) the entire folder structure of your project.

Comment: The problem with compressing the whole ios folder is Gmail won't let me send it due to some 'security issue', probably an unsupported file

Comment: This seems like an excellent time to learn to use a version control system.

Comment: @MarksCode You can zip the entire directory and upload the zip file to google drive and share with your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HelloCordova.xcodeproj` file doesn't contain your source code. It just contains the instructions on how to compile your source code and build your app.

You might want to zip the `ios` folder, which appears to contain your source code. Right-click on the `ios` folder and choose ‘Compress “ios”’ from the menu:

[image: compressing ios folder]

But if that `platforms.json` file is also part of your source code and you need to include it in the zip file, then you need to go up another level, to the folder that contains both `ios` and `platforms.json`, and zip that:

[image: compressing higher level folder]

You can command-click on the window title to get the pop-up folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If your friend is also having cordova install on mac you can send zip of the main parent folder where www folder is placed from which your friend can build new source of iOS platform (if size is large you can remove platforms from the current source for the zip)

As for the cordova platform if it don't get plugins and other files it may failed in the build/run time and you have to add the plugins again

> but when opened the other files in the ios directory are missing

in the cordova application ios folder is made by cordova automatically in the platform when you add ios platform from cordova cli

Still if you want to zip the files zip all the files inside ios folder and run the project directly if it works, it will not create ios folder in the another mac